# Sha256 opencl kernel needed [Help needed]

Tags: sha256

i need a Sha256 kernel file , i am using Cloo as my opencl library , it will be included in WPF project
i am calculating a hash value several times
the program needs about an 30 mins or so to do that but my search result claimed opencl will reduce that time to under 3 mins or less

thanks in advance

**[Edit]**
ok now i managed to do it using this
https://searchcode.com/file/45893396/src/opencl/sha256_kernel.cl/

but it works fine with string
yet when sending my byteArray header to hash it returned a very different value than expected

**[Edit2]**
it can not handle large arrays any array more than 32 length returns missy results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this and i modified it to calculate double hash

if anyone needs it

```
    #ifndef uint8_t
 #define uint8_t  unsigned char
 #endif
 
 #ifndef uint32_t
 #define uint32_t unsigned int
 #endif
 #ifndef uint64_t
 #define uint64_t unsigned long int
 #endif
 #define rotlFixed(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32 - (n))))
#define rotrFixed(x, n) (((x) >> (n)) | ((x) << (32 - (n))))

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t state[8];
  uint64_t count;
  uint8_t buffer[64];
} CSha256;

inline void Sha256_Init(CSha256 *p)
{
  p->state[0] = 0x6a09e667;
  p->state[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
  p->state[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
  p->state[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
  p->state[4] = 0x510e527f;
  p->state[5] = 0x9b05688c;
  p->state[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
  p->state[7] = 0x5be0cd19;
  p->count = 0;
}

#define S0(x) (rotrFixed(x, 2) ^ rotrFixed(x,13) ^ rotrFixed(x, 22))
#define S1(x) (rotrFixed(x, 6) ^ rotrFixed(x,11) ^ rotrFixed(x, 25))
#define s0(x) (rotrFixed(x, 7) ^ rotrFixed(x,18) ^ (x >> 3))
#define s1(x) (rotrFixed(x,17) ^ rotrFixed(x,19) ^ (x >> 10))

#define blk0(i) (W[i] = data[i])
#define blk2(i) (W[i&15] += s1(W[(i-2)&15]) + W[(i-7)&15] + s0(W[(i-15)&15]))

#define Ch2(x,y,z) (z^(x&(y^z)))
#define Maj(x,y,z) ((x&y)|(z&(x|y)))

#define sha_a(i) T[(0-(i))&7]
#define sha_b(i) T[(1-(i))&7]
#define sha_c(i) T[(2-(i))&7]
#define sha_d(i) T[(3-(i))&7]
#define sha_e(i) T[(4-(i))&7]
#define sha_f(i) T[(5-(i))&7]
#define sha_g(i) T[(6-(i))&7]
#define sha_h(i) T[(7-(i))&7]


#ifdef _SHA256_UNROLL2

#define R(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, i) h += S1(e) + Ch2(e,f,g) + K[i+j] + (j?blk2(i):blk0(i));\
  d += h; h += S0(a) + Maj(a, b, c)

#define RX_8(i) \
  R(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, i); \
  R(h,a,b,c,d,e,f,g, i+1); \
  R(g,h,a,b,c,d,e,f, i+2); \
  R(f,g,h,a,b,c,d,e, i+3); \
  R(e,f,g,h,a,b,c,d, i+4); \
  R(d,e,f,g,h,a,b,c, i+5); \
  R(c,d,e,f,g,h,a,b, i+6); \
  R(b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a, i+7)

#else

#define R(i) sha_h(i) += S1(sha_e(i)) + Ch2(sha_e(i),sha_f(i),sha_g(i)) + K[i+j] + (j?blk2(i):blk0(i));\
  sha_d(i) += sha_h(i); sha_h(i) += S0(sha_a(i)) + Maj(sha_a(i), sha_b(i), sha_c(i))

#ifdef _SHA256_UNROLL

#define RX_8(i) R(i+0); R(i+1); R(i+2); R(i+3); R(i+4); R(i+5); R(i+6); R(i+7);

#endif

#endif

static const uint32_t K[64] = {
  0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5,
  0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
  0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3,
  0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
  0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc,
  0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
  0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7,
  0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
  0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13,
  0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
  0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3,
  0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
  0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5,
  0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
  0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208,
  0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
};

inline static void Sha256_Transform(uint32_t *state, const uint32_t *data)
{
  uint32_t W[16];
  unsigned j;
  #ifdef _SHA256_UNROLL2
  uint32_t a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
  a = state[0];
  b = state[1];
  c = state[2];
  d = state[3];
  e = state[4];
  f = state[5];
  g = state[6];
  h = state[7];
  #else
  uint32_t T[8];
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    T[j] = state[j];
  #endif

  for (j = 0; j < 64; j += 16)
  {
    #if defined(_SHA256_UNROLL) || defined(_SHA256_UNROLL2)
    RX_8(0); RX_8(8);
    #else
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) { R(i); }
    #endif
  }

  #ifdef _SHA256_UNROLL2
  state[0] += a;
  state[1] += b;
  state[2] += c;
  state[3] += d;
  state[4] += e;
  state[5] += f;
  state[6] += g;
  state[7] += h;
  #else
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    state[j] += T[j];
  #endif
  
  /* Wipe variables */
  /* memset(W, 0, sizeof(W)); */
  /* memset(T, 0, sizeof(T)); */
}

#undef S0
#undef S1
#undef s0
#undef s1

inline static void Sha256_WriteByteBlock(CSha256 *p)
{
  uint32_t data32[16];
  unsigned i;
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    data32[i] =
      ((uint32_t)(p->buffer[i * 4    ]) << 24) +
      ((uint32_t)(p->buffer[i * 4 + 1]) << 16) +
      ((uint32_t)(p->buffer[i * 4 + 2]) <<  8) +
      ((uint32_t)(p->buffer[i * 4 + 3]));
  Sha256_Transform(p->state, data32);
}

inline void Sha256_Update(CSha256 *p, __global const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
  uint32_t curBufferPos = (uint32_t)p->count & 0x3F;
  while (size > 0)
  {
    p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = *data++;
    p->count++;
    size--;
    if (curBufferPos == 64)
    {
      curBufferPos = 0;
      Sha256_WriteByteBlock(p);
    }
  }
}

inline void Sha256_Final(CSha256 *p, __global uint8_t *digest)
{
  uint64_t lenInBits = (p->count << 3);
  uint32_t curBufferPos = (uint32_t)p->count & 0x3F;
  unsigned i;
  p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = 0x80;
  while (curBufferPos != (64 - 8))
  {
    curBufferPos &= 0x3F;
    if (curBufferPos == 0)
      Sha256_WriteByteBlock(p);
    p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = (uint8_t)(lenInBits >> 56);
    lenInBits <<= 8;
  }
  Sha256_WriteByteBlock(p);

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i] >> 24);
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i] >> 16);
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i] >> 8);
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i]);
  }
  Sha256_Init(p);
}


inline void Sha256_Update1(CSha256 *p, const uint8_t *data, uint32_t size)
{
  uint32_t curBufferPos = (uint32_t)p->count & 0x3F;
  while (size > 0)
  {
    p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = *data++;
    p->count++;
    size--;
    if (curBufferPos == 64)
    {
      curBufferPos = 0;
      Sha256_WriteByteBlock(p);
    }
  }
}

inline void Sha256_Final1(CSha256 *p, uint8_t *digest)
{
  uint64_t lenInBits = (p->count << 3);
  uint32_t curBufferPos = (uint32_t)p->count & 0x3F;
  unsigned i;
  p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = 0x80;
  while (curBufferPos != (64 - 8))
  {
    curBufferPos &= 0x3F;
    if (curBufferPos == 0)
      Sha256_WriteByteBlock(p);
    p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    p->buffer[curBufferPos++] = (uint8_t)(lenInBits >> 56);
    lenInBits <<= 8;
  }
  Sha256_WriteByteBlock(p);

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i] >> 24);
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i] >> 16);
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i] >> 8);
    *digest++ = (uint8_t)(p->state[i]);
  }
  Sha256_Init(p);
}


__kernel void Sha256_1(__global uint8_t *header,__global uint8_t *toRet)
{
    uint8_t tempHdr[80];
    uint8_t tempDigest[32]={0};
    uint startNon=toRet[0] + (toRet[1] << 8) + (toRet[2] << 16) + (toRet[3] << 24);
    uint maxNon=toRet[4] + (toRet[5] << 8) + (toRet[6] << 16) + (toRet[7] << 24);
    uint nonce =startNon;
    uint32_t finalNon=0;
    uint8_t match=0;
    for(int x=0;x<80;x++)
        tempHdr[x]=header[x];
    
    tempHdr[76] = (char)(nonce);
    tempHdr[77] = (char)(nonce >> 8);
    tempHdr[78] = (char)(nonce >> 16);
    tempHdr[79] = (char)(nonce >> 24);
    while(finalNon<1)
    {
        CSha256 p;
        Sha256_Init(&p);
        Sha256_Update1(&p, tempHdr, 80);
        Sha256_Final1(&p, tempDigest);
        
        CSha256 p1;
        Sha256_Init(&p1);
        Sha256_Update1(&p1, tempDigest, 32);
        Sha256_Final1(&p1, tempDigest);
        for(int x=31;x>21;x--)
        {
         if(tempDigest[x]<1) match++;
        }
        if(match>8) 
        {
            finalNon=nonce;
            toRet[8] = (char)(nonce);
            toRet[9] = (char)(nonce >> 8);
            toRet[10] = (char)(nonce >> 16);
            toRet[11] = (char)(nonce >> 24);
        }
        else
        {
            nonce++;
            tempHdr[76] = (char)(nonce);
            tempHdr[77] = (char)(nonce >> 8);
            tempHdr[78] = (char)(nonce >> 16);
            tempHdr[79] = (char)(nonce >> 24);
        }
        match=0;
        
        if(nonce>maxNon) break;
        if(nonce<=startNon) break;
    }
}
```